# Why is an outdated version of a Ruby script used when running Ruby from a Subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, subprocess, popen, thor

I'm trying to run a Ruby project from a Python interface, but in its most current form it only works when run from a terminal, not from a Subprocess in Python. The Ruby project consists of an executable file (let's call it `exeFile`) which runs a command-line interface tool (let's call it `cli.rb`), which requires and calls various structures from various other Ruby files in the project. The CLI file takes command-line arguments via Thor. This works in a terminal, but fails in a subprocess call when the `cli.rb` file has been modified.

I've made sure I'm passing all the right arguments to `subprocess.Popen`. For example:

```
popen = subprocess.Popen(['/home/daveshere/.rbenv/shims/ruby', '/media/daveshere/Data/exeFile', '--b', '1.1.1', '-p'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
```

The `p` argument hasn't changed in the `cli.rb` file, and works in both the terminal and the Subprocess. But days ago, I changed the type of `b` from `numeric` to `string`, which allows the program to run properly. Again, this works in the terminal, but not when running from the Subprocess. Instead, printing the Subprocess output shows me the error:

```
Expected numeric value for '--b'; got "1.1.1"
```

This is despite the `cli.rb` file requiring a `string` type for `b` now, and the fact that the same call works in the terminal. It seems as if there is some locally-cached outdated version of the `cli.rb` file being called by ruby in the Subprocess, but not the terminal. I even tried adding this to the `cli.rb` file to see if it registers:

```
puts "TESTING MODIFICATION"
```

That string prints when running from the terminal, but not from the Subprocess (although other, older output does).

I also made sure `ruby -v` returns the same version in both cases, and it does. I'm really not sure what's causing the disconnect here. I'm also running the Python Subprocess via Pycharm on Ubuntu, if that has any relevance. Any ideas?

Comment: try to wrap the initiation of your subprocess inside a shell script file like `init.sh`. And then make sure to init `rbenv` like you do in the normal terminal. Then call what you want. Just to make sure is anything related to the paths.

Comment: I don't see you calling the CLI in the subprocess? It seems like you are passing the arguments directly to the exe but you have obfuscated the post to the point where it is difficult to tell. Additionally if the CLI was gemified in someway and that is what is being loaded then your changes will have no impact unless you manually change the gem (bad idea) or republish the gem

Comment: Welcome to SO, but you need to be clear and provide a [mre] and debugging details.  Why do you call a ruby script as 'exeFile'? And where's its implementation?

Comment: @engineersmnky The exeFile runs the CLI. It's a minor detail which does obfuscate things, but I had to include it just in case it was part of the problem. I think you might be right about the gemification though. Will look into it soon. Thanks.

Comment: @manuwell The shell script idea might not work because the ruby program takes command-line inputs while it's running, which in this case are being specified and inputted via the python interface. You could be right that it's related to paths.

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm using Bundler to manage the gem, and re-making the gem doesn't seem to fix it. Thanks though.

Comment: @DavesHere how are you using bundler to manage the gem? Are you pulling the gem from Git or from ruby gems? Can you post the line from the Gemfile? If you are pulling it from Git you need to make the changes and push. If from rubygems then you will have to fix the gem, change the version, republish the gem to rubygems, and then update the Gemfile to use the new version and rebundle

Comment: @engineersmnky The Gemfile consists of: `source "https://rubygems.org"` and `gemspec`. So is the terminal running the local version of the gem while the subprocess is running the publicly-available version, do you think? I'm still in the troubleshooting stage, so trying to keep it as local as possible for the time being.

Comment: @DavesHere unfortunately without more detail I have reached the end of the road here. It is possible the CLI has a local bundle or a gemset. It is possible you are not editing the correct file. There are alot of possibilities that cannot be ascertained from the post. What is clear is that the changes you are making are not having the desired impact. For testing purposes you could change the path in the Gemfile to reference where you are making changes and go from there. Try this: https://rossta.net/blog/how-to-specify-local-ruby-gems-in-your-gemfile.html

Comment: @DavesHere You can receive the inputs from the bash script to the ruby cli inside it like: `init.sh arg1 arg2` and inside the `init.sh` you can forward to the cli like: `cli.rb -b $1 -p $2`

Comment: @manuwell I understand that, but unfortunately those arguments would need to be chosen and inputted as the program was starting. The program requires user input after it's started and before it's finished.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it thanks to [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky)'s help. For whatever reason, the Subprocess, regardless of whether `shell=True` or `shell=False` was used, whether bash was or wasn't used, whether `env=os.environ` was used, etc., could not read the ruby environment, including the local changes to the gem. It could only read the git-published changes. I'm a ruby/gem newbie, so the reason wasn't obvious to me.

I didn't have ownership of the repo for the gem I was editing, so I [created a private fork of the repo](https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/github-how-to-make-a-fork-of-public-repository-private-6ee8cacaf9d3), moved my local changes to that repo, edited the *.gemspec file to reflect the changes, and [built and installed a new gem locally](https://medium.com/@bernardomg/build-a-private-ruby-gem-b5f53dc2e911) with the same name. Now everything works. All I have to do now is remember to add my local changes to the private git and reinstall as needed when new changes are made. Technically, maybe I could have just added the local changes to the public repo without committing anything, but I'd prefer playing it safe with the private repo.

Comment: It would be better to edit the question for clearness, instead of posting a useless answer.